# PrimeVue ConfirmDialog: Emit not working inside accept function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I am using PrimeVue ConfirmSerivce to open a dialog in a child component.
When the user confirms the dialog, I want to call a function in the parent component from the child. I am trying to use emit but it's not being called from inside the accept function for an unknown reason.

Child Component:

```
<template>
  <h1>Hello, I am the Child</h1>
  <Button type="button" label="PrimeVue Button" @click="handleClick"></Button>
</template>

<script>
import { useConfirm } from "primevue/useconfirm";

export default {
  emit: {
    callParent: Function,
  },
  setup(props, ctx) {
    const confirm = useConfirm();

    const handleClick = () => {
      console.log("clicked");
      confirm.require({
        message: "Do you want to delete this record?",
        header: "Delete Confirmation",
        icon: "pi pi-info-circle",
        acceptClass: "p-button-danger",
        accept: () => {
          ctx.emit("call-parent");
        },
      });
    };
    return { handleClick };
  },
};
</script>
```

Parent Component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h2>PrimeVue Issue Template</h2>
    <child @call-parent="callback"></child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from "./Child.vue";

export default {
  components: { Child },
  setup(props, ctx) {
    const callback = () => {
      console.log("callback clicked");
    };
    return { callback };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There were following problems in you code:

1. You should have the `<ConfirmDialog />` component.
2. The Event definition should be done with `emits`, not `emit`
3. The name of custom event should be in `kebab-case`

like this

```
emits: ['call-parent'],
```

Here is the fixed `Child.vue`

```
<template>
  <h1>Hello, I am the Child</h1>
  <Button type="button" label="PrimeVue Button" @click="handleClick"></Button>
  <ConfirmDialog></ConfirmDialog>
</template>

<script>
import { useConfirm } from "primevue/useconfirm";

export default {
  emits: ['call-parent'],
  setup(props, ctx) {
    const confirm = useConfirm();
    const handleClick = () => {
      console.log("clicked");
      confirm.require({
        message: "Do you want to delete this record?",
        header: "Delete Confirmation",
        icon: "pi pi-info-circle",
        acceptClass: "p-button-danger",
        accept: () => {
          console.log('accept')
          ctx.emit("call-parent");
        },
      });
    };
    return { handleClick };
  },
};
</script>
```

And here is the working [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cori-4s8jx1?file=/src/Child.vue:0-748)

Comment: Tolbxela Thanks for your answer,
Actually, my problem was is something else,
Concerning point one, I placed the <ConfirmDialog /> in App.vue so am fine.
Concerning point two, emit as an object and emits as an array both works.
Concerning point three, the name of the event could be in kabab-case or camelCase and both work fine

Comment: I thought the app in the Codesandbox solves your problem, since the callback is also called in the main App. What is your problem then?